# Find line containing "string_a" and then replace matching "string_b"

Tags: powershell

I have a json config that I want to *sed* in Powershell. Here is the entry in config.json:

`"gateway.public.host": "http://placeholder.ourdomain.com",`

I want to find the line matching the string `gateway.public.host` but I want to replace the word `placeholder` on that line.

Most examples I find on Powershell is find a match and replace that match.

Comment: Why not use `ConvertFrom-Json` and find the object `$object."gateway.public.host"` make your changes and `ConvertTo-Json` again. If you have structured data you could browse it better that way. Especially if you have other changes to make.

Comment: @Matt I am new to Powershell, I would prefer the sed-equivalent. But your answer is equally helpful. Thanks.

Comment: You can do as you may.... If you are new to Powershell it would be beneficial to use the tools as best you can! If not you can just use regex with capture groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex approach would be obvious here. Match everything from the beginning of a line up until and including "placeholder" with a capture group replacing the text after the capture group leaving the remaining line intact.

```
(Get-Content $file) -replace "(.*gateway.public.host.*)placeholder", '$1ReplacementText'
```

A host of other regexes will work here as well.

---

However we can also leverage the *power* in PowerShell with the cmdlets `ConvertFrom-Json` and `ConvertTo-Json`

```
$json = '{
    "gateway.public.host": "http://placeholder.ourdomain.com"
}'

$jsonObject = $json | ConvertFrom-Json
$jsonObject."gateway.public.host" = $jsonObject."gateway.public.host" -replace "placeholder", "holdplacer"
$jsonObject | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5
```

Which will get you

```
{
    "gateway.public.host":  "http://holdplacer.ourdomain.com"
}
```

Yes, I will concede that there is more code there. Depending on what you are starting with and where you want to end up your code will be cleaner using this method.

Answer (score 1):

Replace is kind of the SED equivalent. Seeing as you're new to Powershell I'd go with the first method.

If your scenario really is that specific:

```
$Json = Get-Content filename.json
$Json = $Json -replace ("`"gateway.public.host`": `"http://placeholder.ourdomain.com`"","`"gateway.public.host`": `"http://newvalue.ourdomain.com`"")

$Json | Set-Content filename.json -Force
```

Or you can do it in one-line

```
(Get-Content filename.json).replace("`"gateway.public.host`": `"http://placeholder.ourdomain.com`"","`"gateway.public.host`": `"http://newvalue.ourdomain.com`"") | Set-Content filename.json
```

In Powershell `cat` is an alias for `get-content` so you could even do this if you want to 'feel' more linux:

```
cat filename.json | %{$_ -replace "`"gateway.public.host`": `"http://placeholder.ourdomain.com`"","`"gateway.public.host`": `"http://newvalue.ourdomain.com`""} | Set-Content filename.json
```